# Different rules for the same user using cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan

I'm new to rails, and I'm having a terrible doubt here, I was developing and I got to the point where I saw that the rules I had created were not going to behave anymore.
I'm using the cancancan.

Let's say I was going to develop in modules, to facilitate delivery and development. Currently only one of these modules is available, the rules that have been defined, for this module are working perfectly, but when I deliver another module, they will not be the same rules for the same user.

```
enum kind: {
        User: 1,
        Editor:2,
        Admin: 3       
    }
    enum charge: {
        Auxiliary: 1,
        Analyst: 2,
        Coordinator: 3
    }
    enum print: {
        No: 0,
        Yes 1
    }
```

these are the options available today, this is for the user model in relation to the document model.
But when I create a model test that the rules are totally different from the document, will I have to duplicate the user rules to be able in my ability to define?

```
enum kind_test: {
        User: 1,
        Editor:2,
        Admin: 3
    }
    enum charge_test: {
        Auxiliary: 1,
        Analyst: 2,
        Coordinator: 3
    }
    enum print_test: {
        No: 0,
        Yes 1
    }
```

and when I create another module, will I have to duplicate again? My rules in user will always be these kind, charge, and print, what changes is in the ability the different models.

My ability

```
if user.kind == 'Admin'
    can: manage,: all
end
if user.kind == 'User'
    if user.print == 'Yes'
        can: view, Pop
        if user.charge == 'Auxiliary'
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
        end
        if user.charge == 'Analyst'
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
        end
        if user.charge == 'Coordinator'
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
            can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 3
        end
    else
        can: view, Pop
        if user.charge == 'Auxiliary'
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
        end
        if user.charge == 'Analyst'
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
        end
        if user.charge == 'Coordinator'
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
            can [: show,: read,: view,: index], Pop, status: 0, charge: 3
        end
    end
end
if user.kind == 'Editor'
    can: view, Pop
    if user.charge == 'Auxiliary'
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
    end
    if user.charge == 'Analyst'
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
    end
    if user.charge == 'Coordinator'
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 1
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 2
        can [: index_pdf,: show,: read,: view,: index,: edit], Pop, status: 0, charge: 3
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  if user.kind == 'Admin'
    can: manage,: all
    return
  end

  pop_permissions = pop_permissions_to_apply

  can :view, Pop
  can(pop_permissions, Pop, status: 0, charge: 1)
  if user.charge == 'Analyst' || user.charge == 'Coordinator'
    can(pop_permissions, Pop, status: 0, charge: 2)
  end
  if user.charge == 'Coordinator'
    can(pop_permissions, Pop, status: 0, charge: 3)
  end

#####
def pop_permissions_to_apply 
  permissions = [:show, :read, :view, :index]
  user_that_can_print = user.kind == 'User' && user.print == 'Yes'
  if user_that_can_print || user.kind == 'Editor'
    permissions.push :index_pdf
  end
  if user.kind == 'Editor'
    permissions.push :edit
  end
  permissions
end
```